# Ajax call is not working from http to https?

Tags: http, https

I am restricted some folders in my server to http and https using htacess, In some of my non https pages, I need to call a ajax script (php) which is using https (In the same domain), it is not working (https to https are working fine ).

I have tutorials/ path which is rewritten to use http only, i have one more folder(path) ajax/ rewritten to use https and I am making a call from tutorials/ to ajax/, it is failing.

Comment: Can you show your codes ? PHP / JavaScript ?

Comment: Way too many things to consider which can't be simply inferred from your post.

Comment: Are you able to browse the page using https which you are calling using ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the restriction of ajax for security reasons that you can not access any https page from http page. It is recommended that If you want to use https then all of the pages in your website must be accessed using https. To ensure this you should use relative path. If you use related path then http or https will automatically be calculated based on the source page from where you are accessing other page.

Comment: I have restricted tutorials/ to http only for some SEO prospects and ajax/ to https, I have to call ajax script from tutorials/ path to ajax/ path, ajax scripts are in ajax/ (https)...call is failing.

Any suggestions.....

Comment: You need to divide your application in two parts, http pages and https pages. There should not be any cross page access between http and https. For you, I would suggest to use https for all your pages since there is no side effect (except minimal performance degrade) of https over http. User should be able to access the pages without any issue. If user enters the url as http then you can redirect http request to https using your server side code logic.

Comment: That is a good suggestion but I am facing some issues with IE, a annoying popup is showing every time. I am also thinking in SEO prospective...

Comment: ha ha ha  :) I had come across this annoying IE popup as well. But we had divided our application as either http page or https page and removed dependency of one type to another. It had solved our SEO problem as well. I have one doubt, you are accessing https page from http page and because http page will use SEO but in that case you are not supposed to call https page from http page. It would be considered as bad design.

Comment: That is right...I have structured to keep all ajax scripts in one folder....I think I can restructure it, I am using only two scripts from non https page.....thanks for your responses, and helped me.